# undefined is not an object with Async/Await method

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

I am implementing a login functionality with firebase and React Native and keep getting this error when I use async method:-

[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'result2.failed')]

```
export default async function login(credentials) {
    let result2= succeed();
    result2 = await handleLogin(credentials.email, credentials.password);
    if(result2.failed()){
       return fail({password: "Login failed"});
    }
    else{          
       return succeed();
    } 
}
const handleLogin = async(email,password) => {
    try{
        auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .catch(function(error) { 
                console.log(error); 
                return fail("failed");
         })

     }catch(e){
            return fail("An error occurred");
     }
```

Edit: I removed the try catch blocks and did:

```
auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) { console.log(error); return fail("failed");})
return succeed();
```

This seems to have solve that error but now my code is always returning succeed(). Any thoughts?

Comment: `handleLogin` doesn't **return** anything in the non-error branch. You wanted to `return auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(/*...*/);` Without it, the success path returns a promise that gets fulfilled with `undefined`, leading to this error.

Comment: `.catch()` will catch errors, so you don't need `try/catch` around it.

Comment: Did this and now the code's always returning succeed. auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) { console.log(error); return fail("failed");})
return succeed();

Comment: Try `auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword().then(succeed).catch(fail)`

Comment: putting 'return succeed()' in .then() gives undefined object error